# Where to license non-automotive POIs for France, Spain and Portugal?

Tags: data, gps, point-of-interest

qualified POIs are needed for a commercial project - should cover broad out-of-car usecases (*not* needed: parking, gas stations). Could be commercially licensable data or derived from national geodata portals and INSPIRE related initiatives. Or something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

There is always the option to get data from [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)

Comment: Hi Rowland. Sure - OSM would be an option if commercial licensability would be granted.

Comment: Commercial 'licensability' doesn't need to granted; using OSM under the current (CC) license or future (ODBL) license for commercial purposes is allowed by the license. You still have to meet the requirements of the license, but 'no commercial use' isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it isn't clear that OSM licensing wouldn't be compatible with your project.  There are some minor commercial projects using OSM (http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2010/08/02/bing-maps-adds-openstreetmap/)

I guess it really comes down to whether your project is about the data or an application that can use data with an open license.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked into NAVTEQ or Teleatlas data? Both of these companies do provide POI data.

Comment: Sure - I am well aware of both. My question wasn't clear enough as I meant to say: "POI data complementing to NVT/TA outside automotive focus".

Comment: Not sure why you think Navteq POIs are automotive focused? In general, they have very complete POI data for many different things, from restaurants to bars to hotels to pharmacies. Whether you can afford to pay for it, of course, is another question.

Answer (score 0):

For France, [IGN](http://www.ign.fr/) sells some POI layers in its database called "[BDTopo](http://professionnels.ign.fr/ficheProduitCMS.do?idDoc=6180211#top)". For a description of these data, see section 12 of [the data specification document](http://professionnels.ign.fr/DISPLAY/000/506/447/5064472/DC_BDTOPO_2.pdf) (it is in French, sorry).

Otherwise, have a look at the [UPCT](http://www.upct.org/) project, that aims at establishing a free database of POIs.

Comment: Thanks Julien, IGN already is under scrutiny. Never heard of UPTC, thanks for the hint! Any _commercial_ POI providers you know?

Comment: sorry, I do not know others.